# Why is my heroku app empty when I clone it (it should be parse-server)

Tags: git, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I created a heroku app using the `Deploy to heroku` button on this page https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

I can check its running by running code similar to the following which returns results in terminal.

```
curl -X GET \               
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ********************" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: *******************" \
  http://MY-APP.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/Speech
```

I want to update the cloudcode, my understanding on how to do this is to git clone the app, make a change, commit then push it back up.

But when I run `heroku git:clone -a MY-APP` it gives me the following warning

```
Cloning into 'MY-APP'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

And the `MY-APP` folder is empty.

*What am I doing wrong?*

It should have something in it right? Otherwise the `curl...` command wouldn't work?

**Edit**: This question and answer solved my problem. Apparently it is a bug with heroku. [How can I host my own Parse Server on Heroku using MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389389/how-can-i-host-my-own-parse-server-on-heroku-using-mongodb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I host my own Parse Server on Heroku using MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389389/how-can-i-host-my-own-parse-server-on-heroku-using-mongodb)

Comment: Heroku fork has the same issue. I used heroku fork --from app_origin --to app_fix and the result is an empty git repository!!

Answer (score 9):

Clone the server and add heroku remote manually:

```
git clone https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example.git your-app-name
cd your-app-name
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/your-app-name.git
```